# array_search() with array_column() is very slow, how can I speed this up?

Tags: php

Hi all I have the following function (With the internal stuff cut out) :

```
    /**
     * @param int $lastSyncTimeStampLocal
     * @return void
     */
    protected function compareData(int $lastSyncTimeStampLocal): void
    {
        $time_start = microtime(true);

        foreach ($this->localData as $row) {
            $key = array_search($row['uuid'], array_column($this->masterData, 'uuid'));
        }

        $time_end = microtime(true);

        $execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;

    }
```

This function is to compare 2 sets of data. The problem is the array_search is very slow with large amount of data.

eg if $this->localData and $this->masterData both contains 10000 records then this functions takes approximately 30 seconds to complete. I am wondering if there is an alternative/ any thing I can change to make this a lot faster?
Note uuid is a string like 'dkdue29u29dbiyedh92dye'

Thanks for any help

Comment: Without knowing anything else about your data, Nigel's approach would be best. But if, for example, the list of UUIDs is already sorted then a binary search could be used, avoiding the need to build the index. Depending on the format and desired operations, it would also be possible to load these lists into slightly fancier datastructures than simple arrays for more efficient set comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to test with large result sets, but I hope this works out.

First thing is not to repeat any operation in the loop if you can.  So the `array_column` call is moved outside the loop.

Rather than using `array_search()`, using the values as the keys means you can just do an array reference. BUT using `array_flip()` on it's own would mean that you would end up with the last occurrence of rather than the first one.  So this code uses `array_reverse()` followed by `array_flip()` to mean that you end up with a array keyed by the uuid with the value being the position in the array.

(May be worth printing out the `$uuids` array to see what I mean by this).

Then inside the loop, you just use a straight forward array access with `$uuids[$row['uuid']]` and use `?? -1` which sets -1 when the value is not present.

```
$uuids = array_flip(array_reverse(array_column($this->masterData, 'uuid')));
foreach ($this->localData as $row) {
    $key = $uuids[$row['uuid']] ?? -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, and for the detailed explanation. This has pretty much knocked 29 seconds of :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it reduces my loading time significantly! (45s -> 1s.) In my case (non-uuid) I don't need the array_reverse()